# Encode Facebook Share URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET MVC 5 I have the following Facebook share link:

```
@{  
  var link = String.Format("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={0}&p[title]={1}", "http://mysite.xyz", "This is my site");

}

<a href="@link">share in facebook</a>
```

When I validate the resulting html I get the following error:

```
Bad value http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://mysite.xyz&p[title]=This is my site for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query component.
```

I tried to encode such as HttpUtility.UrlEncode, HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode, ...

But I either loose the tittle, get local host before the path, get security problems because of having %20 or the page HTML is not validated ...

What is the correct way to define the anchor?

**UPDATE**

I am now trying the following:

```
@{   
  var link = String.Format("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={0}&p[title]={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://mysite.xyz"), HttpUtility.UrlEncode("This is my site"));    
}

<a href="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(link))">share in facebook</a>
```

But I am not able to get this validated in HTML Validator. I get the error:

```
Bad value http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http%3a%2f%2fmysite.xyz&p[title]=This+is+my+site for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query component.
```

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to solve all social share links but one is still giving me some problems.

I have the following mailto link:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="
  @String.Format("mailto:?subject={0}&body={1}", 
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ViewBag.Info.Data.Title), 
  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ViewBag.Info.Data.Description 
  + "%0D%0A" + 
  ViewBag.Info.Data.Url))>Share by Email</a>
```

This is not validated and if I use the same approach as the social links I get all the strange characters in the mail body and subject.

Can this be solved?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should URL encode the values of your query string parameters:

```
var link = string.Format(
    "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Burl%5D={0}&p%5Btitle%5D={1}", 
    Url.Encode("http://mysite.xyz"),
    Url.Encode("This is my site")
);
```

and also use `Html.AttributeEncode` when generating your anchor:

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(link))">share in facebook</a>
```

Comment: I still get a error on HTML Validator: Bad value "sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http%3a%2f%2fmysite.xyz&p[title]=This+is+my+site" for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query component.

Comment: Try URL encoding the keys as well.

Comment: What do you mean? I am encoding the way you said ... I think ... I just updated my question with what I am using now.

Comment: Please anyone? I have tried everything I could think of ... And I can't find a solution for this.

Comment: No, you are encoding only the values. You should also encode the names of the parameters. `p[url]` -> `p%5Burl%5D` and `p[title]` -> `p%5Btitle%5D`. I have updated my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: Darin, I was able to solve the social links with your code. I still have a problem when sharing through "mailto:". I updated my original question to include that. Could you, please, help me?